# How to run keywords into multiple times

Tags: robotframework

My scenario:

There is field called "**search first value**" i have to click on Then click on Submit.

I have to repeat this step more than 100 times. How can i do in Robot framework?

**MY code:**

```
[Documentation]   Resubmit
 wait until element is enabled   ${CLICK_RESUBMIT}
 click element   ${CLICK_RESUBMIT}
 sleep   2s
 confirm action
 repeat keyword  5times Go to Previous Page
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard library have keyword `Repeat Keyword`

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Repeat%20Keyword

Comment: Click on Resubmit
     [Documentation]   Resubmit
     wait until element is enabled   ${CLICK_RESUBMIT}
     click element   ${CLICK_RESUBMIT}
     sleep   2s
     confirm action
     repeat keyword  5times

Comment: this is my code still i am facing issue? could you please clarify?

Comment: Format it and post it in the question body/

Comment: can u check now?

Comment: Still I am not sure what are you trying to do. It looks like you just copied first line from example from link that posted in answer. If you want to perform some action multiple time than you should use keyword Repeat Keyword in combination what action you want to repeat.

Comment: i want to repeat this line  click element   ${CLICK_RESUBMIT}. but i am unable to do..once confirm action completed.