# FOR loop contains no keywords

Tags: robotframework

This is my Keyword which i want to repeat more than 500 times. So I have tried FOr loop, i got a message FOR LOOP CONTAINS NO KEYWORDS.

```
test_case 1.0 -> Click on Resubmit

 wait until element is enabled  ${CLICK_FIRST}
 click element  ${CLICK_FIRST}
 wait until element is enabled   ${CLICK_RESUBMIT}
 click element   ${CLICK_RESUBMIT}
 confirm action
 sleep   5s
  :FOR  ${CLICK_FIRST}  IN  @{10}
  Run Keyword If    ${CLICK_FIRST} == 'CONTINUE'    Continue For Loop
```

Comment: There is no indentation.

Answer (score 3):

In RF statements which are suppose to execute inside for loop are followed with the \ with 
tab
Your for loop will look like this and it will iterate over 100 times

```
:FOR   ${Index}  IN  0  100
\    Run Keyword If ${CLICK_FIRST} == 'CONTINUE'    Continue For Loop
```

other way as you asked for

```
:FOR   ${Index}  IN  0  100
\    Click on Resubmit    ${LOCATOR}
\    Run Keyword If ${CLICK_FIRST} == 'CONTINUE'    Continue For Loop
```

********** **Edit** **********

New syntax of for loop is introduced after robot framework release 3.1 -
[Here is the release notes](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#for-loop-enhancements)

new syntax of for loop will look like this -

```
FOR   ${Index}  IN  0  100
     Run Keyword If ${CLICK_FIRST} == 'CONTINUE'    Continue For Loop  
END
```

1. there will be no more ***":"*** before *FOR* word and no ***"\"*** ahead of every statement inside for loop.
2. for loops nowadays end with an explicit ***END*** marker

Comment: Still i am getting For loop contains no Keywords.

Comment: oops! it was reverse of it use this ' \ '   instead /   also please keep in mind there is *tab* or 4 time space between \ and  starting of keyword

Comment: replace `@{10}` with   `IN RANGE      1      11`    this will start your for loop at 1 and end at 10

Comment: FOR loop has no loop values. i am getting like this after i replaced with IN RANGE 1 11

Comment: i refer your code for answers, dont know what you doing by putting ` ${CLICK_FIRST}`  in for loop, you can iterate list in for loop OR can run for loop in particular range, for ex    `@{ElementList}=   Create List   ${CLICK_FIRST1}      ${CLICK_FIRST2}   ${CLICK_FIRST3} `    `:FOR    ${Element}    IN   @{ElementList} `

Comment: this will iterate your for loop for 3 times on list  @{ElementList}  , also you can add reference for site where you doing this and rephrase your question

Comment: i want to Repeat this Keyword(Click on Resubmit.) for multiple  times like 100 etc...The method which i am following correct??? i

Comment: please be more clear I don't see any such keyword in your question , the bold statement above the code is **Click on Resubmit**  is your keyword which has logic below it am i right? if yes it will differ..more, else small changes will do your job

Comment: i will check,, Actually Click on Resubmit is a test case Step..under that  my codes are there..i want to repeat that test cases name multiple times,, hope you are clear now?

Comment: you should add it properly, In your previous comment you said it is keyword,now you said it is test case, anyways, you can add for loop at beginning of your test case and add your inner for loop under another keyword, it should work

Comment: No keyword with name 'Run Keyword If ${CLICK_RESUBMIT} == 'CONTINUE'' found                                                                                        Click on Resubmit
     [Documentation]   Resubmit
     wait until element is enabled  ${CLICK_FIRST}
      :FOR   ${Index}  IN  0  100
     \              click element    ${CLICK_FIRST}
     \              Run Keyword If ${CLICK_RESUBMIT} == 'CONTINUE'    Continue 
     confirm action

Comment: I had already mentioned your answer , actual answer was edited for your previous queries, now u tried wrong. please read my previous comments, Also don't repeat question for same queries and don't change your question after you got first answer, ask separate question. also this question seems around this problem of yours only  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259584/how-to-run-keywords-into-multiple-times)